# how to show the position of moving div in another div

Tags: jquery

I am going to design a bar with the gauge that on loading of the page moves on the bar until it gets to the number that is defined for it and stops:

My code is as follow:

```
<div id="t1" class="grad" style="background-color:Aqua;width:100px;height:20px;float:leftmargin-top:4px">
<div id="d" style="width:100px;height:20px; float:left;margin-top:4px;font-size:13px;">tone63%</div>
</div>
<div id="t2" class="top-to-bottom" style="float:left;width:0px;height:28px;border-right-  color:#FCE805;border-right-style:solid;border-right-width:4px;position:absolute;">
</div>
```

and the javascript :

```
            $("#t2").top = $("#t1").offset.top;
        $("#t2").left = $("#t1").offset.left;
        $("#t2").animate({ width: 60 }, 3000);
```

Here is the jfiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/hminaee/wGkxc/4/

Now the problem is: if you see the text inside the bar it is written  63% all the time but I want it dynamic by that I mean as the gauge is moving on the bar the number is changing(showing the position of gauge on that bar)

I appreciate if anyone can help me?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this (See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyvk/KvHmW/2/))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a callback of `animate` (`step` or `progress`), see http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Example:

```
$("#t2").top = $("#t1").offset.top;
$("#t2").left = $("#t1").offset.left;
$("#t2").animate({ width: 60}, {duration: 3000, progress: function(){
    $('#d').text('tone '+$(this).width()+'%');
}});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGkxc/10/